# Почему не выводится параметр метода?

Tags: java

Параметр метода подчеркнут на скрине[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: А ты сам понимаешь, что ты написал?

Comment: А что вставить код не скрином, а текстом религия не позволяет? Как и прочитать текст ошибку которую явно сообщает вам IDE.

Comment: Компилятор выдает ошибку только когда я вставляю тот кусок текста который подчеркнул

Comment: Вопрос остается в силе:  ты сам понимаешь, что ты написал? Поясни свои действия

Comment: таким образом можно вывести значения полей класса, но никак не значения аргументов для метода. В Java нет такого синтаксиса и лучше что то почитать по этому языку прежде чем писать подобный код

Comment: Поясню более подробно что я хочу от программы. Прошу прощения за малую информативность. Это мой первый вопрос на этом сайте, и я еще не разобрался толком что тут  чему. В данное время я прохожу курс javarush (наверное вы знаете этот ресурс). Познакомился с методами, объектами. И вот решил написать простейшую программу которая бы просто выдавала результат от деления. В общем я хочу чтобы она в данном примере вывела мне: "Яйцо = 0,0024". Я мог бы конечно вместо "Cost1Energe.nameEat" просто ввести "Яйцо", но хочу теперь понять почему компилятор выдает "ошибку символов" в первом случае

Comment: pavlofff, ответ вроде твоего я и ожидал услышать. Я склонялся к тому что параметры методов в отличии от классов не выводятся на экран. Рыть информацию более подробно в интернете об этом мне не хотелось. Слишком много времени и так трачу на различные обучающие курсы. Решил воспользоваться этим ресурсом

Comment: ошибку символов выдает, потому что у вас нет класса Cost1Energe к которому мог бы быть применен подобный синтаксис. так же вам нужно сразу усвоить конвенцию по именам в Java, в частности имена методов пишутся с маленькой буквы. так же если вы хотите обратится к участнику, то его ник нужно писать с символа @ (как @Слава) тогда он получит ваше сообщение

Comment: Спасибо за развернутые ответы! Я завтра еще более подробно их изучу. Я благодарен вам

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка заключается в том, что вам надо вместо

```
        System.out.println(Cost1Energe.nameEat + " = " + Cost1Energy("Яйцо", 3, 0.072));
```

написать

```
        System.out.println("Cost1Energe.nameEat = " + Cost1Energy("Яйцо", 3, 0.072));
```

Так как у вас `Cost1Energe.nameEat` это текст, а далее, вы корректно указали метод, который вам вернет результат равный `0.072/3`. Конечно, в данном случае, вам текстовый параметр не нужен, так как он нигде не используется. Я сейчас про `Яйцо` говорю. Но, видимо, вы его потом куда-то будете использовать.

**P.S.**

Если вы хотите получить в консоле ответ вида `Яйцо = 0.024`

То у вас много вариантов как это сделать, например так

Изменить весь ваш метод

```
public static void Cost1Energe (String nameEat, int sumEnergy, double cost) {
    System.out.println(nameEat + " = " +  sumEnergy/cost);
}
```

или, если вам так угодно, то сделать так

```
public static Pair<String, Double> Cost1Energe(String nameEat, int sumEnergy, double cost) {
    Pair<String, Double> pair = new Pair<>(nameEat, cost / sumEnergy);
    return pair;
}

 public static void main(String... args){
        Pair<String, Double> pair=Cost1Energy("Яйцо", 3, 0.072);
        System.out.println(pair.getKey()+ " = " + pair.getValue());
}
```

и еще много другого.

**P.S.S**

Ах, да, самое главное то и забыл, почему у вас ошибка. Потому что вы пытаетесь вывести в консоль аргумент вашего метода. Тут несколько ошибок в ваших действиях:
1) Самая главная - это то, что вы еще метод не вызвали, а пытаетесь обратиться, допустим к его полю `Cost1Energe.nameEat`
2) Вы в принципе, не можете так обращаться к аргументам метода, потому что это не класс. Только в классе вы можете обращаться так к полям, например, если бы это был бы вот так

```
public class Cost1Energe{

String nameEat;
int sumEnergy;
double cost;

 public String getNameEat() {
        return nameEat;
    }

    public void setNameEat(String nameEat) {
        this.nameEat = nameEat;
    }

    public int getSumEnergy() {
        return sumEnergy;
    }

    public void setSumEnergy(int sumEnergy) {
        this.sumEnergy = sumEnergy;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

 }
```

Тогда, вы могли бы обратиться к полю класса как

```
Cost1Energe costEnergy=new Cost1Energy();
costEnergy.getNameEat();
```

3) Ваш метод возвращает только double, как вы и указали, собственно вы не можете получить и `String` и `double`. У меня представлен вариант, как можно получить оба варианта. Но `Pair<>` объект дороговат в обращении и в данном случае, он лишний, поэтому лучше использовать первый пример, где в консоль выводится всё внутри самого метода.

Comment: судя по заголовку вопроса эта нелепая запись вовсе не должна быть текстом

Comment: Видимо, вы всё таки правы, поправлю ответ